# samba's ping_pong test on glusterfs

Tags: samba, glusterfs

Has anybody been able to pass samba's ping_pong test (https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Ping_pong) on glusterfs? I have used different versions of glusterfs (3.5.x, 3.6.3, 3.7.5) on both CentOS6/CentOS7/Ubuntu14.04 and it never can pass any of the items in the ping_pong test (lock coherence, I/O coherence, mmap coherence). Comments would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently successfully run ping_pong on fedora-based gluster clusters. Gluster and ctdb (which ships ping_pong) installed from the fedora (22) repos.

It passes the lock coherency and I/O coherence tests. Don't bother to try the mmap coherence test... In my case, I mostly ran on 3-node replica-3 setups, but also 2x2 setups.

We've made sure these work with Gluster some time ago, so if you are experiencing problems, we need to know more about your setup: Software sources, setup of the gluster-cluster. Exact ping_pong commands executed. ...

Comment: "You should see that the locking rate drops dramatically." For lock coherency test, what kind of drop did you experience? My number was not that great to begin with (~1500 locks/sec) and when I started the same command (ping_pong test.dat 3) on my second node, it dropped to ~1300 locks/sec. Hardly dramatic as the wiki page would suggest.

Comment: The note with the lock rate is not 100% correct. I.e. if your initial lock rate for a single process is not great, you will not see a dramatic drop when the contention of additional processes kicks in. The ping_pong tool does not have a convenient way to reliably test that lock coherence works, buy it is possible: use`ping_pong file 2` on two nodes, and you should see messages `lock at 1 failed! - Resource deadlock avoided`.  If you see these, lock coherence works, if you don't seen them but both processes happily write lock rates, then lock coherence is broken.

Comment: Thank you. Thanks to your confirmation and tips, I set aside a few hours to try again. And by carefully weeding out old info, I was able to get the combination of haproxy+ctdb+smb+glusterfs to work.